# Use Vim to edit Applescript file

Tags: vim, git, applescript

Is it possible to use Vim to work on applescript files rather than the default Automator or Script Editor program?  I searched the webs and couldn't find the same question or an answer anywhere.  I have located the file under Library > Services, but seems that it is in a format that would be rather difficult to work with in Vim.

Basically what I would like to do is to manage the applescript I have just like any other code I do, with it living in a common repo, using Vim to edit, manage it as part of my git workflow, and to run the file from the location of my choosing.  I am still researching these other parts, but I am curious if anyone has done something similar?

Seems I can't paste in an example, but basically the log 'hello' that I enter in Script Editor file, becomes unreadable when opened with Vim.

Comment: Hello, what is the exact issue here? You mentioned "format", but you need to be way more specific as to what's the problematic part of that that you want to fix. I don't see any reason why Vim wouldn't be able to deal with AppleScript files. Unless you are trying to edit a compiled version?

Comment: sure, so I've created a sample Applescript in Script Editor app and saved it.  Whene I open the same file in Vim it comes out as unreadable.  Must be compiled but how can I write the simple script using vim and load it with Automator rather than being forced to use ScriptEditor?